# problem with events in flex using boxes

Tags: apache-flex

i have following problem, when i create box in action script and whe i addEventListner for drop accept, and if i add this box to some parent box, then this event is not working, if i add this event to not child but to parent box, then it is working, what can i do if i want create many boxes, add to them events listners and then add them all to some other parent box?

Answer (score 0):

1. Post your code you want get working.
2. Use dynamic addEventListener adding to each component, and also add this function to parent boxes too, in all cases.